# Older steam heating with integrated hot water

Tags: steam

...Generates steam when heating water for shower & washer operation. Enough steam is produced to cause radiators throughout the home to heat up, which is clearly wasteful. We are new to this type of system and while it seems plausibly normal that an older system might lack controls to prevent this, wanted to ask: Is there anything we can do to better isolate both systems so that heat is not lost to steam when producing hot water?

Comment: I take it the hot water pipes run out of the actual steam boiler in your system? Also, is your steam system a one-pipe or a two-pipe system?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As @ThreePhaseEel said, we'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sounds like I need to research the difference between one- and two-pipe configurations. I'll start there, thanks Eel.